# How do you get the absolute paths for multiple file selections using jfilechooser from an array of file names in java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

below is the source code for attaching multiple files.

```
public void doAttachFile(){
 try {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int selection = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(selection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){// if open button is clicked
            File [] selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        }
}catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error attaching files\n"+e.toString,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

}

How do you get the absolute paths for the selected files from the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through each `File` object and get the absolute path of the file as shown below:

```
File [] selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
for(File file : selectedFile) {
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath(); //gives the absolute path
    System.out.println(absolutePath);
}
```

Comment: Will try it out and give feedback @javaguy

Comment: Will try it out and give feedback @javaguy